# Laravel 4 authentication with multi database table

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

How can I do authentication with multiple database table in Laravel?

For example, I have 3 tables:
1. General User Login table
2. Membership detail table
3. CMS user detail table

When user login from the CMS or the member login, the Auth will go and verify from the "general user login" table. But how can I make the Auth function also getting info from the second or third table depend on the user type? Then, I can access those info via something like `Auth::user()->address`, which the address is stored in the membership detail table.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you define the relationships between the different models? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create relationship columns, to relate your user to data in other tables:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function membership()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Membership');
    }

    public function userDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CmsDetail');
    }

}

class Membership extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'membership';

}

class CmsDetail extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cms_details';

}
```

Then you can just

```
echo Auth::user()->membership->member_since;

echo Auth::user()->userDetails->address;
```